# SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust (SPY) CALL and PUT options

Tags: options

Does the buying of CALL or PUT options of SPDR S&P 500 ETF Trust (SPY) work the same way as buying of CALL or PUT options of individual stock like **FB** or **AAPL** or **MSFT**? Can a trader sell the SPY options (CALL or PUT) before the expiration date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. Options on an ETF work just like options on a stock.